# Ошибка Cannot infer type arguments for Array<> как можно исправить?

Tags: java, массивы, generics

Ошибка в строке:

```java
Array<T> result = new Array<>(arr.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
```

Вот часть кода:

```java
class Array<T> {

    T[] arr;
    private int size;
    public Array(Class<T> c, int size) {
        arr = (T[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(c, size);
        this.size = size;
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        return arr[index];
    }

    public void set(int index, T value) {
        arr[index] = value;
    }

    public int length() {
        return size;
    }

    public Array<T> add(Array<T> other) {
        Array<T> result = new Array<>(arr.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            T element1 = arr[i];
            T element2 = other.get(i);
            if (element1 instanceof Number && element2 instanceof Number) {
                Number sum = ((Number) element1).doubleValue() + ((Number) element2).doubleValue();
                result.set(i, (T) sum);
            } else if (element1 instanceof String && element2 instanceof String) {
                String concat = (String) element1 + element2;
                result.set(i, (T) concat);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported Type");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Метод `getComponentType()` возвращает тип `Class<?>`. Приведите его к `Class<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Кроме проблемы с преобразованием типа, которую можно решить при помощи кастинга согласно комментария от @Byb:

```java
Array<T> result = new Array<>((Class<T>) arr.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
```

в методе `add` есть и другие проблемы, связанные с типом результата сложения отдельных элементов.

Данный код отработает только если создан массив чисел с двойной точностью `Array<Double>`

```java
if (element1 instanceof Number && element2 instanceof Number) {
    Number sum = ((Number) element1).doubleValue() + ((Number) element2).doubleValue();
    result.set(i, (T) sum);
}
```

Для любого другого численного типа будет выброшено исключение:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Double
```

в строке метода `set`:

```java
arr[index] = value;
```

так как результат `sum` получит тип `Double` после боксинга результата (`Number::doubleValue` возвращает примитив `double`!), а у массива будет к примеру тип `Integer[] arr`.

Поэтому следует принудительно использовать методы `valueOf` классов-обёрток и затем ещё приведение к типу `T` (плюс ещё кастинг к "коротким" целочисленным типам, так как оператор `+` автоматически расширяет до `int`):

```java
public Array<T> add(Array<T> other) {
    Array<T> result = new Array<>((Class<T>)arr.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        T element1 = arr[i];
        T element2 = other.get(i);
        if (element1 instanceof Number && element2 instanceof Number) {
            Number n1 = (Number) element1;
            Number n2 = (Number) element2;
            Number sum;
            if (n1 instanceof Double) {
                sum = Double.valueOf(n1.doubleValue() + n2.doubleValue());
            } else if (n1 instanceof Byte) {
                sum = Byte.valueOf((byte)(n1.byteValue() + n2.byteValue()));
            } else if (n1 instanceof Float) {
                sum = Float.valueOf(n1.floatValue() + n2.floatValue());
            } else if (n1 instanceof Short) {
                sum = Short.valueOf((short)(n1.shortValue() + n2.shortValue()));
            } else {
                sum = Integer.valueOf(n1.intValue() + n2.intValue());
            }
            result.set(i, (T) sum);
        } else if (element1 instanceof String && element2 instanceof String) {
            String concat = (String) element1 + element2;
            result.set(i, (T) concat);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported Type");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```